# Java from 2 hashmap print key for which value does not match

Tags: java, hashmap, key

The code below does not work. What logic can I use to print the key Job which has 2 different values in 2 hash maps?

```
public void randomTest() throws IOException {

        HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

        map1.put("Name", "Jones");
        map1.put("Job", "QAE");

        map2.put("Name", "Jones");
        map2.put("Job", "Developer");

        // ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> mm1 : map1.entrySet()) {
            hs.add(mm1.getValue());
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> mm2 : map1.entrySet()) {
            hs.add(mm2.getValue());
        }

        for(String s: hs){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
       /* for (Map.Entry<String, String> mm1 : map1.entrySet()) {
            for(String str: hs){
               if(str.equals(mm1.getValue())){
                   System.out.println(mm1.getKey());
               }
            }
        }*/

    }
```

Expected output: Job.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic does the job (no pun intended).

```
    HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map1.put("Name", "Jones");
    map1.put("Job", "QAE");

    map2.put("Name", "Jones");
    map2.put("Job", "Developer");

    Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> mm1 : map1.entrySet()) {
        String map2Value = map2.get(mm1.getKey());
        if (! Objects.equals(mm1.getValue(), map2Value)) {
            hs.add(mm1.getKey());
        }
    }

    for(String s: hs){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output:

> Job

I have added a comparison of the values from the two maps. Furthermore I am doing `hs.add(mm1.getKey());` instead of `hs.add(mm1.getValue());` to have the non-matching *key/s* printed.

It’s also a nice case for applying a stream operation if you like. If so, use the code from the answer by Oboe.

The code assumes that the keys are the same in both maps. You should probably check this assumption and issue a message if it doesn’t hold.

Answer (score 1):

Try these:

```
map1.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> map2.get(entry.getKey()) != null)
            .filter(entry -> !map2.get(entry.getKey()).equals(entry.getValue()))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Like. May use `Collectors.toSet()` so we get a `Set` as in the question.

Comment: I don't think you need a Set here since keys are unique in a HashMap

Comment: You are completely correct. Only use if you have other reasons for preferring a `Set`. Like telling the consumer that there can’t be any duplicates. Or passing to an API that requires a `Set`.

Comment: I agree, a Set may be needed for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do:

1. Iterate over the **keys** of both of your maps and collect them into a `Set`.
2. For each entry in that `Set`, query values from both maps.
3. Compare the values. Make sure your code handles cases when there's no value in one of the maps for the given key. Whether to consider that a mismatch, or an exceptional condition, is up to you.